# When is it considered a win vs a draw?

Tags: rules, threefold-repetition

I am playing with black and have just called check on the white king. It is now the white players turn, no matter what move the white king makes it will lead to check. Does this mean black has won or is it considered a draw?[image]

```
[fen "r5nR/p2b4/npp1pk2/3p3Q/P2P1p2/R1P1qP1N/1P2PKB1/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: What's stopping the king from just moving back a square? I don't see any piece giving check if it just goes straight back. Unless I'm just not seeing a piece.

Comment: This position leads to a threefold repetition (which is a DRAW), as White can move the King to e1/f1 and ...Qc1+ forces the King back to f2, where ...Qe3+ forces the King back again. As Black is material down and has nothing better than this, Black should force the draw by repetition.

Comment: @B.Swan That sounds like an answer.

Comment: I removed the "stalemate" tag and replaced it by these two as this is not stalemate, but rather threefold repetition (if black chooses to repeat the checks).

Answer (score 4):

This position leads to a threefold repetition (which is a DRAW), as White can move the King to e1/f1 and ...Qc1+ forces the King back to f2, where ...Qe3+ forces the King back again.

As Black is material down and has no compensation, Black should force the draw by repetition.

```
 [FEN "r5nR/p2b4/npp1pk2/3p3Q/P2P1p2/R1P1qP1N/1P2PKB1/8 w - - 0 1"]

 1. Ke1 Qc1+ Kf2 Qe3+ Kf1 Qc1+ Kf2 Qe3+
```